# How can I use HTML + Javascript to build a python GUI?

Tags: python, webkit

I have been experimenting with Appcelerator Titanum yesterday and I think it's cool when it comes to Javascript.

Python features on Appcelerator Titanum are so limited (can't use some modules for example).

**My question is How can I use html & javascript as a GUI tool for a *real python application* ?**

I am running windows 7 and i was thinking of using **webkit** for that purpose but couldn't know how to work with it in python.

I am planning to make a standalone executable using py2exe as I don't know if the users always have python and the appropriate modules installed.

Comment: So you want to write a locally hosted web application?

Comment: So basically, you want your application logic to be written in Python, and the GUI in HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: @musicfreak: That's true, that's what I want.

Answer (score 8):

If you're after webkit bindings for Python, look at PyQt, which includes Webkit, as well as wxWebkit (http://wxwebkit.wxcommunity.com/) if you're using wxWidgets. This lets you embed webkit in a Qt or Wxwidgets app so that you won't have to go through a browser.

If you do use this, then you can either use a web server in Python, like others have mentioned, or you can control the Webkit control directly (though I'm not sure how practical this is).

Beyond that, there's also Pyjamas Desktop (http://pyjs.org/), which lets you use Pyjamas to build the application, then run it.

Answer (score 4):

[pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/) might be what you are looking for.

"HOWTO Create Python GUIs using HTML" http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/

http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/07/how-to-build-a-desktop-wysiwyg-editor-with-webkit-and-html-5.ars

But I'm not sure if it runs on Windows.

PyQt and Webkit would work on Windows.

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/webkit-pyqt-rendering-web-pages/

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/the-browser-interface-local-server-bils-application-1957143) is a nice PyCon talk on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

> So how can I use html & javascript as a gui tool for a real python application ?

You run a web server on your desktop.  For example, this: http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html  In a few lines of code you can provide a complete HTTP server that will serve your HTML and Javascript to a browser.

> I am running windows 7 and i was thinking of using webkit for that purpose but couldn't know how to work with it in python actually moreover I wanna use py2exe so how can I use python + webkit to handle the gui part ?

Hard to parse that.  It either indicates too much coffee or no familiarity with punctuation.

Randomly, I'll pick the following words as possibly being meaningful.

> how can I use python + webkit to handle the gui part ?

You run a web server on your desktop.  The web server provides html and javascript pages to a browser -- also running on your desktop.

Comment: Sorry but that's a lame answer of my question ! If you don't know so don't comment. I mentioned at the beginning of the question that I was impressed by Appcelerator Titanum so I just need more freedom using python while doing the same thing as Appcelerator Titanum.

Comment: @Lettuce: Please **Clarify** your question.  I found all the "?" I could find.  I tried to parse the questions.  If you don't like the answer, think about this for a moment.  Maybe your question isn't complete enough for someone to understand it.  Think that -- perhaps -- we don't know as much as  you and you need to explain a little of what you're trying to do and what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at htmlayout? http://terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/main.whtm

Answer (score 1):

> PHP Desktop is an open source project founded by Czarek Tomczak in
>   2012 to provide a way for developing native desktop GUI applications
>   using web technologies such as PHP, HTML5, JavaScript & SQLite. The
>   development workflow you are used to while creating web applications
>   remains the same. The step of turning an existing website into a
>   desktop application is basically a matter of copying it to the "www/"
>   directory.

PHP Desktop also releases Python Desktop and Ruby Desktop. It allows you to create a Windows app, that either uses the installed IE for the front-end, or uses an instance of Chrome (so definitely HTML5 support too) that is packaged with the app. It starts a local webserver, supports many databases with a PDO driver and you can layout the views in HTML and Javascript. You can download external resources like any other website/webapp, so it supports network related stuff too. The app ships with its own bare-bones version of Python, you can add libraries as desired.

I looked at all the answers before, as I had the exact same question as you, but PHP Desktop easily solved it for me.

https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/wiki/EmbeddingOtherScriptingLanguages

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are mobilizing a web-application for cross platform access.

If so have you considered abstracting the cross platform access at the web-app presentation layer ?

Appcelerator / Webkit does not provide true native look-and-feel on mobile devices but this is where a new technology can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about real desktop applications that are multi-threaded and/or use multiple system component - forget about JavaScript. That requires a very good SDK (like PyQt4), and not a basic wrapper like Appcelerator Titanium. Note that developing such applications takes a lot of time.

Second option is to drop the desktop binding and make a web application with an advanced frontend UI made with one of JavaScript frameworks & friends (Ember, Angular... up to things like dhtmlx and alike widgets). Those can't use system components (like access some hardware), but they can provide nice services.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pySide](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/)

I suggest using [QtWebKit](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtWebKit/index.html)

And you can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) if you want to hide the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TideSDK that can help you creating beautiful and unique desktop apps using your web development skills (HTML5 / CSS3 / JavaScript / Python or PHP or Ruby).

Website: http://www.tidesdk.org

Using Python in TideSDK: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/using_python

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: It seems that TideSDK and TideKit are both now defunct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440371/is-tidesdk-defunct