# Is TideSDK defunct?

Tags: tidesdk, tidekit

I am interested in creating a desktop application using HTML5+webkit, and I'd like to be able to build a stand-alone executables for various target platforms like a .exe file for Windows and a .dmg image for Mac OS. I have played around with [node-webkit](https://github.com/shama/nodewebkit), which seems nice except for the packaging / distribution portion. I also stumbled on [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/), but that project seems to be inactive. For example, the latest release I saw was a beta from November of 2012. Yet, it seems the core developers have switched to developing [TideKit](https://www.tidekit.com/) instead.

Does anyone here know if TideKit is intended as a replacement for TideSDK? Is TideSDK going away? etc.

Comment: fyi anyone passing by: TideKit is defunct – don't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron (http://electron.atom.io/) is the new way to go.

I also had an app running on TideSDK (https://github.com/vinyll/worktimer.titanium) and I'll have to migrate it to Electron.

Answer (score 14):

Well, TIDE is now officially a dead project. I just got this email about 15 minutes ago.

> TideKit.com and TideKit have been discontinued.
>
> TideKit was software for developing apps for all platforms
>   simultaneously with a single base of code written in JavaScript.
>
> The scope and complexity of the product made it difficult to
>   assemble the platform all at once. This stemmed from a holistic
>   approach to app development for all platforms. While creating a
>   platform for JavaScript developers, much of the core engineering is in
>   a variety of lower level languages that affect the speed of
>   development. We considered delivering parts of our platform as we
>   reached milestones, but this was not suitable for the start of trials.
>
> We were widely criticized for not revealing our technical innovation
>   in advance of our release. In a competitive environment, revealing
>   advantages as you go can also mean assimilation as you go. We had
>   already witnessed how quickly our technical advantages could be
>   assimilated by competitors to our open source TideSDK product.
>   Therefore, we held back with a view of delaying the duplication of
>   features by competitors, increasing our technical barriers and working
>   to protect our IP and business case until we felt we were ready.
>
> In a startup, we talk about a Minimum Viable Product (MVP). In our
>   case, our minimum viable product was much larger and more difficult to
>   achieve. In total, approximately three years of research and
>   development was committed with multiple developers working greater
>   than full time hours. A factor that extended the development was an
>   expansion of scope that aimed to lower friction in the app development
>   process.
>
> In Feb 2014, we created a system to queue developers with
>   reservation system for the earliest possible access to TideKit. Our
>   goal was to provide an early trial when it became available. Since the
>   development itself was complex, we could not provide a date when
>   ticket holders could start the trial process – but it would be
>   following our betas, then moving forward as we scaled the platform.
>
> We were clear with our language on the site concerning reservations.
>   As a result, we expected little confusion about what was being
>   purchased, our expectations of timing to market, or the terms of
>   purchase for a reservation ticket. Purchasers were not paying for our
>   product at this point, but for their position in a queue for a trial
>   of our new technology. We also included a refund policy to ensure the
>   terms of purchase for your ticket were available. The wait has been
>   long, but not nearly as long as other difficult engineering challenges
>   including Myo that pre-sold their product and were also delayed before
>   successfully rolling out.
>
> Throughout the development cycle we provided updates of our status
>   via posts roadmap page, email to our ticket holders and communications
>   on our social channels. We did our best as a team to open ourselves to
>   questions and maintain a social presence.
>
> At the end of May 2015, we communicated our strategy to execute a
>   series of focused betas that would have seen the platform revealed
>   publicly and incrementally. We were at a stage that parts of the
>   platform needed developer feedback as we rolled these out
>   consecutively.
>
> In the days preparing for our first public beta, we recognized the
>   extent to which our brand had been poisoned by our timing to market. A
>   campaign of negativity that had begun several months earlier with
>   followers and ticket holders had taken its toll on our team, brand,
>   and business.
>
> We believed the beta releases would soon bring an end to the
>   negative talk. On July 8 and 9 we faced further eruptions on social
>   media that reached the tipping point. With the discussion no longer
>   about the product nor its future, this was far more serious.
>
> We failed to bring the product quickly enough for you. As a result,
>   we came to the serious decision to discontinue TideKit and dissolve
>   our company.
>
> We wish to thank everyone involved that worked on the product and with
>   our team. This includes businesses, entrepreneurs and supporters of
>   our vision for app development.
>
> Your TideKit Team

Comment: Yeah got that one too.  I think if they have some decency they should open source what they have just so we can see if they actually did anything with the money they collected from a fairly large number of people.   I have to think they did any maybe some value can be extracted from that code.

Comment: 3 years of R&D thrown away because of a couple months of rumors? That doesn't add up. I wasn't interested in a proprietary solution, so didn't buy in and am not planning to press further, but this statement seems like it's leaving out some important parts of the story. What "poisoning"? What "eruptions"? Sounds more like a convenient excuse to cover up lack of progress.

Comment: If you looked closely at their "latest reservations" you'll notice that they're nothing more than pre-determined customer names/countries listed in the source and rotated through by a timer -- misleading to say the least.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d83b28f8b93badbf5b99
https://web.archive.org/web/20150317094608/https://www.tidekit.com/reservations

Comment: I paid and now I feel like an idiot. And probably I deserve it.

Comment: I found it weird that there is no presence of the product online anymore. They seems so close to delivering something so I must assume that whatever happened it was one of the following: 1. It was a big fat scam. 2. They were acquired for their technology and the price was so big they felt ashamed of sharing this with us. 3. they realized that what they had was not working (which I think is the best option). In the end I was looking forward to it.

Comment: They have started with a functional product: TideSDK. This makes option 1 and 3 a bit unlikely. And the fact that they have removed any information about both TideKit and TideSDK is suspicious. But of course they could have done this out of frustration (never underestimate mad people).

Comment: Feel sorry for anyone who paid, view this Twitter handle for details:
https://twitter.com/TideKitLawsuit

Answer (score 9):

you are right, TideSDK is aging and pretty inactive today. And you're also right, we as a core team completely focus on TideKit now. TideKit is the future!

If you want to know the full story about why we stopped working on TideSDK and started TideKit, I recommend you to read our first Q&A. There you'll also find an answer about how we compete with node-webkit:

https://blog.tidekit.com/post/your-questions-our-answers-01

We've just reached the highest HTML5 score any app development platform ever achieved. If you want to know more about builds, like the ones you mentioned for Windows and OS X, you should read this

Desktop Builds
https://blog.tidekit.com/post/from-a-desktop-perspective-tidekit-for-tidesdk-developers

Comment: Thanks, it's always nice to get an authoritative answer (i.e. from a core team member), and BTW welcome to StackOverflow :) Your product looks very appealing (though the hype about HTML5 scores seems moot as one can grab the latest snapshot of webkit/chromium, bundle it, and get 517+), and I wish you and your customers all the best. As for me, however, I'm really not interested in any commercial solutions in this space, so I think it's truly unfortunate that continuing development of TideSDK as an open source project was not financially viable.

Comment: @iX3 In fairness, TideKit is not a repackaging of chromium but has extensive APIs to build web, mobile and desktop apps using HTML5, hybrid and native technologies. Its key feature is the ability to create for virtually all platforms from a single source of code. The recent 505 HTML score we celebrated is significant. Currently no modern browser, wrapper, node-webkit, or atom  implements a score this high at present. We are going further of course. Compliance is a high priority to ensure everyone can work with HTML5's full capabilities. Demos are coming next.

Comment: @fairwinds, what do you mean "Currently no modern browser,...,implements a score this high at present"? I just tested my default (Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m) and got a score of 507/555 at [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/s/4576c0212df46621.html)
P.S. I realize there are some really cool features TideKit/TideSDK and they take a lot of developer pain away, which is great. I didn't mean to poo-poo your work; just saying that it isn't ideal for me.

Comment: @fairwinds I find it to be rather bad form to quietly work on a proprietary implementation, all the while continuing to promise that an up-to-date TideSDK will be coming soon (and continuing to take donations, too). Not to mention that you didn't bother to notify the TideSDK userbase about the changes for a very long time.

Comment: @SvenSlootweg We've been clear to state that TideSDK will not be updated and the reasons why. The work remains available for anyone to use. Its alright you feel the way you do, but realize that with any open source project there are no guarantees of continuity. We've been public about our intentions and where we are placing our efforts.

Comment: @fairwinds It took months after the abandoning for the TideKit banner to appear on the TideSDK site, and it *still* doesn't clearly indicate that the project has been abandoned. I have no idea where you have "been clear to state that TideSDK will not be updated and the reasons why", but it's certainly not on the TideSDk site.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new kid on the block for this sort of projects: [atom-shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell) Based in nodejs and used to create the great [Atom editor](https://atom.io/)

Technical differences with node-webkit: https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/development/atom-shell-vs-node-webkit.md

Presentation at JSLA about "Native NodeJS Apps": http://vimeo.com/97881078

Answer (score 2):

If you look at this blog post, they talk about how unsustainable the economical situation is

http://www.tidesdk.org/blog/2013/04/11/tidesdk-in-numbers/

and I can't find the tweet that was stating the reasons behind the transition from one project to another. But I guess that the blogpost speaks for itself.

Anyway, I'm delivering a project written in node-webkit ( because I starded on Tide but for the obvious reasons I had to switch ) and I'm using grunt for packaging and in the end is not that bad.

Comment: OK, that's basically the conclusion to which I came. I was just looking for something more authoritative.