# Cross platform desktop development with HTML5 GUI

Tags: c#, python, html, desktop-application

Short story: is there a way to write a desktop application with a GUI in HTML5 and core in a cross-platform language like python (or even C#/Mono)?

Longer story: I'm a C# developer, for small personal projects I seldom do, running both under Windows and OSX, I use C# (Mono) with a frontend leveraging on [Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto)

I'd like to understand if there's a mature way to achieve the same results using an HTML5 GUI, since I'd like to learn that and believe it could be a good option for near-future Windows desktop UIs (or otherwise a nice tool to have in my skillset). Of course if the code running behind the scenes is C# I'll be more than happy, but also getting my feet wet in another, maybe more cross-platform like python would be good.

At this stage I'm not interested in any mobile-oriented solution.

Comment: For javascript, there is http://nwjs.io/ :)

Comment: Why not write a web app that launches in browser frame-less 'app mode' and use a local server like nodejs. The web app model is pretty 'mature'.

Comment: One could try bridge.net. It is a C# to JS transpiler, so you write code in .NET and gets executed as JS/HTML5. It seems to have a C# API for HTML manipulation, so you dont have to necessarily directly deal with HTML. There is also cshtml5.com which is just the same except it is C# and XAML instead of pure C#. If you don't necessarily care about HTML5 then the best option is Xamarin (you write C# with or without XAML) for cross-platform-ness - relatively stable, backed by MS. You get native UI.

Comment: A pure C# + HTML solution would be Sciter. There is a C# binding for it called [SciterSharp](https://github.com/midiway/SciterSharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) (formerly Atom shell) has really matured as of late. In fact it's what VSCode is built on.

[image: vscode]

There's a [great tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/12/15/create-a-desktop-app-with-angular-2-and-electron/) and [starter code](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-electron) on using Angular 2 and Typescript, and you can even use VSCode to write and build it.

For me this is the best way to transition from the WPF world to HTML5.

Comment: I changed from TideSDK to this one as accepted answer, since TideSDK project was discontinued

Comment: there's an incredible amount of apps out there already built on Electron, link: http://electron.atom.io/apps/

Answer (score 3):

the NW.js look pretty promising... you might even be able to use TypeScript which would be much closer to C# than plain ol' js. If you're open to using PHP, you can check out the nightrain project https://github.com/naetech/nightrain.

Answer (score 3):

Give http://www.tidesdk.org/ a try.

Your app will run on Windows 8, MacOS and Linux. You can use HTML5, Javascript and CSS3.

But you can also extend the functionality of your app with a scripting language you are comfortable with. TideSDK currently supports Python, PHP, and Ruby.

Comment: @MrUniverse more than that...  I did a research to find another link and found that TideSDK was discontinued and the company behind was disolved. Very bad news: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31369264/585592

Comment: I removed this as accepted answer since TideSDK was discontinued

Answer (score 1):

I have recently worked with [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), basically a browser component for WPF an WinForms. It works very well and provides kind of a two-way interoperability from website to .NET-app and vice versa. Basically, you:

1. Create a WPF desktop app
2. Include CEFSharp and place a full-screen browser on the window
3. Call methods in JavaScript:

```cs
// .NET
var mainFrame = browser.GetMainFrame();
mainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("any js code");
```

4. Bind a .NET-object

```cs
// .NET
browser.RegisterJsObject("boundObject", this);
```

4. Call methods on a bound .NET-object from the website/JS:

```js
// JS 
boundObject.someMethod();
```

On this basis you could build a mediation layer (ViewModels, controllers, ...) between HTML/JS-UI and .NET logic...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an APP with http://kivy.org/ it is capable to create apps for different systems.

Qt node https://github.com/arturadib/node-qt seems also interesting, but i did not test it myself.

And last https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher

You can create web apps for chrome, which should run in supported systems.

Kivy is a Python solution. Qt node is maybe what you are looking for.

Here are some nice tutorials for kivy:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe_l6XiJ40yGTEqIKugAdTy

Answer (score 0):

[NW.js](http://nwjs.io/)

But it's Javascript (node), not python nor C#.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting project I think is [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef). You basically embed a (stripped down) web browser in your application. For python, many GUI Toolkits are supported. Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/) for more information.

Since you are used to C#, maybe Java with [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html) and FXML is an option. FXML is not HTML but you can style it with CSS as well. You can also use [Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) with it for faster UI creation. Many JVM languages support this toolkit so [Jython](http://blog.elliptium.net/2012/12/use-JavaFX-from-Jython) instead of Java will also work. I will recommend Java however, because the support for other languages, while there, is not perfect yet.

Using C# and the Windows App Store WebView is also an option. You can check [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) for more information.

I am sure there are other options (Kivy, Node.js, etc.) as well. Some of them are already mentioned in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Node-Webkit which is based on nodejs.You can still use some python scripts to do some backend job integrated with Node-Webkit which is easy to deal with.I've already saw some successful applications using this(like wunderlist).TideSDK is another choice but the python support in TideSDK is not mature enough.The Node-Webkit project hosted at 
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/